# Resending collaboration invitations for box.com

Tags: box-api

I have Box API program that creates a folder structure and adds collaborators. Currently I have approximately 45 shared folders and over 200 collaborators.

Is there a way to resend the collaboration invitations through the API as opposed to manually triggering a invitation resend thought the browser interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you can 'tickle' a pending collaboration.  But you might try removing and re-adding every pending collaboration on the folders of interest:

1. [Fetch the collaborations](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-view-a-folders-collaborations) and filter to those that whose `status` is `pending`.
2. Locally reserve the `accessible_by.login` values.
3. [Remove](http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-remove-a-collaboration) each pending collaboration.
4. [Add](http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-add-a-collaboration) a new collaboration for each of the `login` values from step 2.

Comment: Good work around John.   No there isn't an API to resend the invite for those who didn't notice the invite the first time.   Great idea though.